# Interactive plots inside Spyder ipython console

Tags: python, spyder

Is it possible to plot interactive graphics with sliders and buttons directly inside the Spyder IPython console and not in a separated window ? I find the inline mode really convenient but no interaction seems possible yet. I tried %matplotlib notebook but an error occurred. Any tips please ?

Thanks !!

Comment: I tried a few things and don't see this being easily possible, I hope someone else can do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) No, unfortunately that's not possible.